# AWS OpenZFS FS mount connect is stuck (time out)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-fsx

I followed [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fsx/latest/OpenZFSGuide/getting-started-step1.html) and [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fsx/latest/OpenZFSGuide/getting-started-step2.html) tutorial to create and mount fsx.

Sadly the command I run, e.g. `mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4.1 fs-<someid>.fsx.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:/fsx/ /fsx`

,
gets stuck and won't end (unless I define a timeout in the command and then it reaches it).

(I also tried for example `mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4.1 fs-<someid>.fsx.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:/ /fsx`

I tried going to the VPC as suggested by other SO posts and in the inbound rules allowed all tcp and udp ports. Sadly nothing worked.

I think that maybe it has something to do with the routing table but I really don't have much knowledge in this.

Comment: looks like the issue is with the '/' after the fsx name
"sudo mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4.2 fs01234567.fsx.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:/fsx /fsx"
also, you can check the mounts on the FSX with showmount command (showmount -e fsx-name)